# multiple texture sets when exported to substance

Tags: texturing, materials, export

Im having a problem when exporting to substance, after I fixed a few parst of my model the fixed parts are exported as different texture sets.
Any way to fix these?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think Substance Painter separates the mesh into texture sets based on what material the faces use. Make sure that your exported mesh only has as many material slots as you want to have texture sets.

Comment: I recalculated normals, erased materials and created new ones and still got the same error.
Only thing that worked was exporting the model, reimporting and re uv unwrapping. But I used the same base mesh for 7 characters so i dont want to repeat the same process 6 times more.

Comment: Have you tried merging the objects by desired texture set / made sure that there are no empty meshes? Do you have multiple UV sets?